# Dependency injection conflict when more than one user uses the system

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I made a single Java Application using Tomcat(Prod) and Jetty(Dev) + Hibernate + Spring + Spring MVC + Fremarker
I have a issue to solve, 'cause the users are reporting that only one user can do login without conflict. If a user does login and tries to create a new entity Payment, he have a successfull transaction. But when another user does login, since then, nobody can create a new Payment.

There is no exception, a POST is executed, but seems like the Controller is not able for delivery the form to services classes.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Persistable, Cloneable {

//code...

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Pagamento extends AbstractEntity{

//code...

}

@Component
@Transactional
public class PagamentoService {

//code...

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/payments")
public class PagamentosController {

//code...

}
```

Is everything okay about Annotations and CDI? What could to be happening?

Comment: More information is required, how you are defining beans, if you are using session management, then its details....the problems can be various, but its not so easy to guess....Check your connectionLimit, your beans, your server settings..

Comment: This issue sounds more like a transaction problem.  Are you committing when your transaction is done?

Comment: None of your annotations are CDI annotations - removed the CDI tag.

Answer (score 1):

A common use case for that is using attributes of controller (or service, dao, etc.) classes. All those beans are singleton beans and are shared between all requests and sessions. You should only use local variables in all those singleton beans - except of course for attributes that are common for the whole application ...

Answer (score 0):

Can it be because you are using a single-connection DataSource, so once a request takes a connection then no other requests can access it until the first one releases the one-and-only database connection.